# suggestion to avoid empty cells from duplicates count

Tags: excel, vba

this is the code i am using to count duplicate values. However, its also counting empty cells. any suggestions to avoid empty cells from count. i would appreciate any help thank you

```
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets("sheet4")
  Dim lngLastRowData As Long
  lngLastRowData = ws.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
  Dim lngLastRowDups As Long
  lngLastRowDups = ws.Range("c1048576").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rngData As Range
Set rngData = ws.Range("A1:A" & lngLastRowData)
Dim lngRowCount As Long
lngRowCount = 0
Dim clData As Variant
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim lngRowIndexData As Long
Dim lngRowIndexDups As Long
lngRowIndexDups = lngLastRowDups + 1
Dim strAlreadySearched As String

For Each clData In rngData.Cells
    lngCount = 0
    If InStr(1, strAlreadySearched, "|" & clData.Value & "|") = 0 Then
        For lngRowIndexData = 1 To lngLastRowData
            If rngData.Cells(lngRowIndexData, 1).Value = clData.Value Then
                lngCount = lngCount + 1
            End If

        Next lngRowIndexData
        If lngCount > 0 Then
            ws.Cells(lngRowIndexDups, 4).Value = lngCount
            lngRowIndexDups = lngRowIndexDups + 1
            strAlreadySearched = strAlreadySearched & "|" & clData.Value & "|"

        End If
    End If

Next clData
```

Comment: Have you tried using "isempty(clData)"?

Comment: tried it, got a compiler error.

Comment: umm , what error ? I just posted your coded with a couple of new lines , can you check whether it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each clData In rngData.Cells
  if isempty(clData) =true then goto sig
    lngCount = 0
    If InStr(1, strAlreadySearched, "|" & clData.Value & "|") = 0 Then
        For lngRowIndexData = 1 To lngLastRowData
            If rngData.Cells(lngRowIndexData, 1).Value = clData.Value Then
                lngCount = lngCount + 1
            End If

        Next lngRowIndexData
        If lngCount > 0 Then
            ws.Cells(lngRowIndexDups, 4).Value = lngCount
            lngRowIndexDups = lngRowIndexDups + 1
            strAlreadySearched = strAlreadySearched & "|" & clData.Value & "|"

        End If
    End If
 sig:
Next clData
```